# c# non-blocking receive socket with try-catch SocketException, performance

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, try-catch, nonblocking

I'm writing a poker-like game and I'm using winodws sockets for the networking. The server is written in C++ and the client in C#. The server uses the  and the client the System.Net/System.Net.Sockets. They have their differences from what I saw.

Ok, so for my send/receive messages functions I use non-blocking sockets. With the server all work perfect. I call my non-blocking send/receive function, I'm sending/receiving all my data perfectly and when there's no data to receive I check the WSAGetLastError and if this error has the famous WSAEWOULDBLOCK error code then I ignore it and move on.

Now, on the client side, if there's no data to receive, then, instead of a function similar to the WSAGetLastError, an exception is thrown, a SocketException with the error code 10035/WSAEWOULDBLOCK. For that, I have my receive function inside a try-catch block. From what I've read, the try-catch block is performance-heavy only when an exception is thrown, if not then it has no serious performance drop. For the message receiving I have a DispatcherTimer with time interval 100ms, it has about 50-60 lines of code inside a try-catch block but the receive is in the second line, and there's where the exception is thrown so it moves to the catch part of the code where there's a simple if block which checks if the exception is NOT a WSAEWOULDBLOCK exception and prints it.

I don't have actually a definitive question I just want some recommendations. My problem:

As soon as the timer start a have a huge performance drop. Is this from the exception throwing? Should I use, instead of a DispatcherTimer, a seperated thread checking for incoming messages? I like the idea of the DispatcherTimer because I don't have to deal with cross-threading operations. Also I sure have read about the Asynchronous sockets but I don't know. Non-blocking sockets seems to me that is a good choice also, for the C++ at least. This C# exception thing is changing the whole thing.

I hope you got pretty much the design of the client. At the server side I'm fine. The client is just a window with a DispatcherTimer runs every 100ms and checks for incoming messages. My problem is performance and simple code design( although I'm not afraid long codes, as long as they are necessary). Thoughts??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used Async sockets and the performance issues disappeared.

Thank you all for your help

Comment: *Codechef* brought me here.